# How to rewrite the where clause so that the exception is not thrown EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I want to filter a dbset using a where clause but both predicates dont work when using `AsQueryable` and
the exception:

> The linq expression could not be translated

is thrown

```
...
var objects = myObject; //Ienumerable

return await dbset.AsQueryable()
.Where(entity => objects.Any(obj => obj.uId == entity.uId &&  obj.cId == entity.cId))
.ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken)
.ConfigureAwait(false); // not working

return await dbset.AsQueryable().
Where(entity => objects.Contains(new Object(entity.cId, entity.uId))
.ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken)
.ConfigureAwait(false); // also not working
```

When I change `AsQueryable` to `AsEnumerable` it is working but since the set can be quite large I want to stick with `AsQueryable`. How could I rewrite the where clause so that the exception
is not thrown?

Comment: The issue is not `AsQueryable()`. You can (and should) remove it. The issue is that `objects.Any` isn't translatable, which `AsEnumerable` conceals in a very expensive manner.

Comment: @GertArnold What would you suggest to use instead of AsQueryable?

Comment: As I said, just remove it.

Comment: @GertArnold Could you explain or link a website that explains why one should not use AsQueryable?

Comment: Why? *Using it* requires an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EF Core` query provider **is unable** to translate certain operations from your **`LINQ` expression to `SQL`** when using `AsQueryable`. The methods `Any` and `Contains` in your current queries are causing this issue.
You must rewrite your query to make it more compatible  EF Core's query translation capabilities.

```
var objectIds = objects.Select(object => new { object.uId, object.cId }).ToList();

return await dbset.AsQueryable()
    .Join(objectIds,
        entity => new { entity.uId, entity.cId },
        objectId => objectId,
        (entity, objectId) => entity)
    .ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Really? Since when joins to inmemory collections are supported?

Comment: @IvanStoev, my comment was a typo. It should not work.